# Apache Log4j Ambiguous Overloaded Method

Tags: java, log4j, overloading

The interface `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` in Apache Log4j 2.12.1 has the following 2 methods:

```
void info(String message, Object... params);

void info(String message, Supplier<?>... paramSuppliers);
```

In my code, my intention was to call the second method and the second arg was a lambda paramSupplier. Surprisingly, at runtime, the first method was called, which printed the lambda's obj reference instead of the actual param value.

I am puzzled why these methods are not flagged as ambiguous by the compiler. This is on Java 11. I also see many other methods, in the same `Logger` interface, where the difference in method signature is just that one method takes an `Object` and the other method takes a `Supplier<?>` in the same position in the args list, with the types and order of all other method args matching.

I found the following two questions re: overloaded methods disambiguation but those answers did not seem to explain this.

1. [Ambiguous method call when overloading method with generics and lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349055/ambiguous-method-call-when-overloading-method-with-generics-and-lambdas)
2. [(Java 8) java.util.function.Supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130659/java-8-java-util-function-supplier)

Comment: Can you post your code? It is hard to help you with your problem if we don't know what you are specifically doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your description, I can suppose that issue is in incorrect package name for `Supplier` interface, as rule we are using `java.util.function.Supplier`, but `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` interface expects `Supplier` interface from `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier` package, the second method will be called after changing the package name.

If everything is as I said above, the question of ambiguity is simple, signatures do not match for the second method and `void info(String message, Object... params);` method will be called as default for unmatched types of parameters, because any class in Java has been extended by `Object` class and any lambda expression is an object.

Comment: Indeed, it was that the package was not the same. The param supplier whose reference was being passed to the `log.info` call was a `java.util.function.Supplier`, which is why it did not match Log4j's concept of param supplier, which is `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier`.

Comment: I checked that, in the following method call ... `log.info("Hello, ", () -> "world!");` the second argument is interpreted as an `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier` and the string `Hello, world!` is printed. However, in my code, I had declared and initialized a `java.util.function.Supplier` instance, and was passing the reference to that. So, it did not match the arg type and was treated just as an `Object` instance. Thanks for helping me notice that detail. :-)